# How do I get accented letter using substring()?

Tags: java, unicode-string

I have the following string: `ąbc`. I'd like to get its first character, ie. `ą`. When I use use the following code
`"ąbc".substring(0,1)`
I get the correct result using `jshell`. However, when using `IntelliJ`, I get `a` instead of `ą`. What's wrong?

[image]

The following unit test works fine (in IntelliJ and in Maven):

```
    @Test
    void test() {
        // GIVEN
        String string = "ąbc";

        // WHEN
        final String substring = string.substring(0, 1);

        // THEN
        assertThat(substring).isEqualTo("ą");
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Also explain in detail how exactly you are compiling your code, which charset encoding you use in your source code and how you run your application.

Comment: @Progman Isn't `"ąbc".substring(0,1)` enough?

Comment: [No](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/LxBcatGDWRy)

Comment: or you can use System.out.println("ąbc".charAt(0));

Comment: And how do you obtain the output? Are you using System.out.println? Are you looking at it in the operating system console or inside an IDE?

Comment: @aled I'm using IntelliJ as IDE. Only then I get the wrong result.

Comment: By the way, `char` is a legacy type, essentially broken since Java 2. One effect of that is `String#substring` can fail with most characters. Make a habit of using code point integers instead.  `System.out.println ( Character.toString ( "ąbc".codePoints ( ).toArray ( )[ 0 ] ) );`

Comment: I wonder if "ąbc" in that program is actually `"\u0061\u0238bc"` rather than `"\u0105bc"`.

Comment: @VGR, as copy and pasted from this page, it's U+0105 (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH OGONEK)

Comment: If you [decompose](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.Form.html) the string first using `String s = Normalizer.normalize("ąbc", Normalizer.Form.NFD);`, then that still prints `ąbc` - but if you try to print the first character you will get a regular `a`: `System.out.println(Character.toString(s.codePoints().toArray()[0]));`. The diacritic mark is separated from the base character. Change `[0]` to `[1]` to see this.

Comment: @andrewJames So how do I get `ą` then?

Comment: *The following unit test works fine:* Clarification please: are you saying that works fine in IntelliJ too?

Comment: I see you have accepted an answer - which is great - problem solved! How specifically did you solve it? What specific change did you make in IntelliJ? (My decomposition comment is just a side note, really. I have to confess, I am surprised IntelliJ would ever automatically decompose `ą` to `a` - but I guess it did!)

Comment: @andrewJames I changed font. The answer suggested this solution.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. What font are you using now?

Comment: Now I use `IBM Plex Sans JP Medm`. Before I used Dejavu Sans, if I remember it correctly.

Comment: Actually Deja Vu Sans has no problem displaying U+0105 afaics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably an issue with your IDE console not being configured correctly for the [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding).

Regardless of the visible character you can confirm it is the right character by printing the hexadecimal value of the character:

```java
      System.out.println(String.format("%04x", (int) "ąbc".charAt(0)));
```

The result should be `0105` for that character.

To display the correct character you may need to change [Intellij's theme](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207053315-Display-utf8-character-on-debugger-) or configuration.

Comment: Per @Basil Bourque's comment, that would be better as  `System.out.printf("%04x%n", "ąbc".codePointAt(0));`